# How to use default keymap for plugin in lazy.nvim?

Tags: neovim, neovim-plugin

I've recently been trying to set up Neovim as my full-time IDE. One plugin which would help my development process quite a bit is [vim-iced](https://liquidz.github.io/vim-iced/#_overview), which I've been able to successfully install in Neovim using the [Lazy Package Manager](https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim), my only issue is that I can't seem to figure out how to enable the default key mappings for vim-iced, I'm assuming I have to do this through lazy?

I've been looking through the Lazy.nvim documentation but I can't seem to find anything on setting keymaps other than:

```
The keys property can be a string or string[] for simple normal-mode mappings, or it can be a LazyKeys table...
```

Which is great if I want to set every individual keymap myself, and I have set two keys for Iced just to verify that the plugin is working correctly, but frankly, the idea of having to individually set every keymap for every plugin that I install, when most already have a well-thought-out keymap already, makes me ill.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take a look into [2.1.1 Installing plugins](https://liquidz.github.io/vim-iced/#installing_plugins) section, there's the
following piece of code, which you'll need:

```
" Enable vim-iced's default key mapping
" This is recommended for newbies
let g:iced_enable_default_key_mappings = v:true
```

So all you need to do, is setting `iced_enable_default_key_mappings` to true. So you can do the following in your config, assuming you have declared the plugin in an extra file:

```lua
return {
    "liquidz/vim-iced",
    config = function()
        vim.g.iced_enable_default_key_mappings = true
    end,
}
```